# Setting value for DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Am trying to set the value for a Razor DropDownListFor control. I have tried just about every method I can think of to set the selected value (short of using js after the control is rendered, which is really a last resort) but when the control renders it still doesn't show the selected value. I can assume I'm missing something really obvious. Here's the code:

```
@{
List<string> arrTitles = new List<string>("Mr,Mrs,Miss,Ms,Dr,Lady,Lord,Prof,Rev,Sir".Split(','));
List<SelectListItem> lstTitle = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (string title in arrTitles)
{
    SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem { Text = title, Value = title };
    if (Model != null)
    {
        if (title == Model.title)
        {
            sli.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    lstTitle.Add(sli);
}
string formHandler = ViewBag.FormHandler;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(formHandler, "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.LabelFor(r => r.title)
@Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.title, new SelectList(lstTitle, "Value", "Text", "Selected"));

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: this sort of c# should be placed in your action method, not your html (as currently this is not in an MVC format)

Comment: If the value of property `title` matches the value of one of the options, then that is what will be selected. You can remove your attempts to set the `Selected` property.

Comment: And all you need is `@Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.title, new SelectList(arrTitles)`. All the code associated with `lstTitle` is unnecessary.

Comment: the title value does match one of the options and if I set a break point where the dropdownlist is generated the value I want to be selected is marked as selected but the list isn't showing the selected value once rendered

Comment: Have tried doing it like that @StephenMuecke and the result is the same

Comment: @jbutler483 I'm well aware of the MVC format. The reason this has been placed in the View is because it's part of a partial view, which is used in multiple Views and controllers around the site. If were to put in the Action method I would have to put it in every action method.

Comment: Then your doing something incorrectly. `List<string> arrTitles = new List<string>() {"Mr", "Ms"};` If `title="Ms"` then  `@Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.title, new SelectList(arrTitles)` will select the 2nd option.

Comment: Or, place it in a function and call the function within the main view?

Answer (score 0):

---

## Short Answer

---

Try using

```
@Html.DropDownList("1stTitle")
```

in which Title is

```
ViewBag.Title = new selectlist(1stTitle);
```

For more information, see [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search), about halfway down the page.

---

## In more detail

---

In your controller, add something like:

```
var Title= new List<string>();

    var listOfTitles= //place list of titles here

    Title.AddRange(listOfTitles.Distinct());
    ViewBag.personsTitle = new SelectList(Title);
```

Then, in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()
    {
    <p>
        title: @Html.DropDownList("personsTitle ", "All")
        
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
    }
```

This follows the **MVC** much better as it keeps your controller code away from your view (which should only really be used to 'view' the results of your code).

Your actual 'selection' code should always be kept within your controller, as that is much better/faster to keep any calculations on the server, rather than the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try like following:

```
@{
List<string> arrTitles = new List<string>("Mr,Mrs,Miss,Ms,Dr,Lady,Lord,Prof,Rev,Sir".Split(','));
List<SelectListItem> lstTitle = new List<SelectListItem>();
string selected = null; 

foreach (string title in arrTitles)
{
SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem { Text = title, Value = title };
if (Model != null)
{
    if (title == Model.title)
    {
        selected = title;
    }
}
lstTitle.Add(sli);
}
string formHandler = ViewBag.FormHandler;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(formHandler, "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.LabelFor(r => r.title)
@Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.title, new SelectList(lstTitle, "Value", "Text", selected));

}
```